# How to return most common login location for each user (duplicates possible) in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

this is my first post so bear with me.

I've been working on a problem with a large data set for about a week now and I am banging my head against the wall. Essentially, I have a database containing records of each time a user accesses a service; each record has a unique ID associated with the user (user_id), an assigned country tag which may differ between accesses (demo_tag) which is a best-guess about a users' geolocation, and a bunch of other information I'm not currently worried about.

What I want to accomplish is to determine which country a user most likely resides in, based on the number of times they've accessed the service with a certain assigned country. In the event of a tie, I want to retrieve BOTH regions (say, a user has logged in equal numbers of times from both France and Belgium, I want to associate the user with both countries). Basically for each user, I want to know the maximum number of times they've logged in from one specific location, and which location(s) it is/they are.

e.g. If I had:

```
user_id region
1       USA
1       CAN
1       CAN
2       MEX
2       MEX
2       USA
2       USA
```

I'd expect to get back:

```
user_id region count
1       CAN    2
2       MEX    2
2       USA    2
```

Right now I have a very ugly, multi-nested query and I feel there must be a better way to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `rank()`:

```
select ur.*
from (select user_id, region, count(*),
             rank() over (partition by user_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by user_id, region
     ) ur
where seqnum = 1;
```